# Apache Ant with Graal VM

Tags: java-11, nashorn, graalvm

We use Apache Ant with Nashorn JavaScript Engine, which became deprecated and removed in jdk 15 and up. I trying find how to switch from Nashorn to Graal VM and didn't find any usable information even on Apache web-site. Please advise which jars I need and were should I put them. what need to be changed in code we have. If somebody already did it, please share your experience.
I have a sample, which run against jdk1.8.0_311:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="test" default="test">
    <property environment="env"/>   
    <target name="test" >
        <script language="javascript">          
            <![CDATA[
            load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
            importPackage(java.time);
            var today = new Date();
            var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
            self.log("This script is for Test Of Nashorn Javascript Engine");
            print ("Today is: " + date );
            ]]>
        </script>
    </target>
</project>
```

Result looks like:

```
test:
   [script] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
   [script] This script is for Test Of Nashorn Javascript Engine
   [script] Today is: 2021-11-3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 6):

## Solution 1

If you are using JDK 15 or above. Please add the below jars to the path.

- [Openjdk nashorn jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core)
- [asm jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm)
- [asm util jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-util)

[image]

## Solution 2

Using Graal VM Jars

- [graal-sdk-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.sdk/graal-sdk/22.3.1)
- [icu4j-72.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/72.1)
- [js-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js/22.3.1)
- [js-scriptengine-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js-scriptengine/22.3.1)
- [launcher-common-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.js/js-launcher/22.3.1)
- [regex-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.regex/regex/22.3.1)
- [truffle-api-22.3.1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.truffle/truffle-api/22.3.1)

Use the above jars and pass them as a classpathref.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could also add [standalone Nashorn](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn) as a dependency to your Ant build; putting it in your Ant `lib` directory should work. By default that's `$ANT_HOME/lib` but some Ant installations use a different location, e.g. homebrew-installed Ant will use `/usr/local/share/ant`. If you don't want to put it in the lib, you can also put it with your project and use `<classpath>` or `<classpathref>` within the `<script>` tag to point to it.

Mind you, standalone Nashorn also needs ASM 7.3.1 on the classpath. JARs for both can be downloaded from Maven Central.

Comment: Solution 1 did the trick:
`<path id="javax.classpath">`
`<pathelement location="D:/dependencies/libs/nashorn/nashorn-core-15.4.jar" />?`
`<pathelement location="D:/dependencies/libs/nashorn/asm-9.7.jar" />`
`<pathelement location="D:/dependencies/libs/nashorn/asm-util-9.7.jar" />`
`</path>` 

`<script language="javascript"`
`manager="javax"`
`classpathref="javax.classpath">`